# I would like to have an where in statement before the select_sum statement

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I would like to have an where in statement before the select_sum statement.
Because i would like to have different sums based on the $project. Now it is just counting all the array variables as a sum.

Im doing this in codeigniter.

model:

```
 function rapport_detail_opbrengsten($idKlant){
                $this->db->from('Project');
                    $this->db->join('Opbrengsten', 'Opbrengsten.idProject = Project.idProject');
    if ($idKlant > 0){
            $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);}
             $query = $this->db->get();
             $project = array();
                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    $project[] = $row->idProject;
                }
                    $this->db->select_sum('Prijs'); 
                    $this->db->from('Opbrengsten');
                                $this->db->where_in('idProject', $project);

                     $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows()>0){
                return $query->result();
             }
            else{
                 return false;
             }
         }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want a `GROUP BY`, so that you get the sum(Prijs) for each individual project?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want to accomplish so. that i get different sum(prijs). But how do i accomplish this? because when i do it like: $this->db->group_by("idProject"); it wont do anything. So i dont know if the GROUP BY is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

`select_sum` groups all your rows .. so there will be no effect if you manually group the rows by other criteria. Try something like this

```
$this->db->select('idProject, SUM(Prijs) as total'); 
$this->db->from('Opbrengsten');
$this->db->where_in('idProject', $project);
$this->db->group_by('idProject');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: for example $project has the values (6,7,8) but i would like to have the select_sum for each value different. When i do it like your example it still is summed together.

Comment: you should get 3 rows with the `ID` and `total`,
are you sure you changed `select_sum` to  just `select` ?

Comment: Yeah i changed it but all id's still have the value of all id's together.

Comment: Sorry can't see the problem, is it possible to get the executed Query ?. Also the whole other parts of the function look suspcieios ..
you reuse `$this->db` several times in nested loops, try to clean it a bit and test with a simpler example.